# how to check if a value from a union is included in an extracted union

Tags: typescript

I need to understand if a value, from a superset of a union type, is matching a [subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) of values obtained through an `Extract`.

It follows an example that shows **a working version** of the code, in which I'm accepting a typed value from the superset (`Omni`), but where I'm forced to duplicate the code that define the subset type (`Mini`):

```
type Omni = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type Mini = Extract<Omni, 'c' | 'b'>

const isMini = (value: Omni): value is Mini =>  {
  /* This body works, but it contains a duplication of the values contained in Mini */
  return ['c', 'b'].includes(value)
  }

const included: Omni = 'b'
console.log(isMini(included)) // true
const excluded: Omni = 'a'
console.log(isMini(excluded)) // false
```

I'm interested in a typescript solution that make possible to maintain the type signature of the function `isMini` and does not include the duplication of the list of values.

NB: [here the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2B5AtgOwJbALzAOQENvAA+OARgcdgMbYCwAUKONHALKpqbACiAHmAE65KYADxI0AGhzUipbAD56jJaEoB7ZAGcwwVJrYcsACgBuuADYBXGAC4EKVAEo7Zq3D3AD6DPJABvFUYAegAqYAAVAAsPEjUAEwhgAHc1fgBrTSkSSx1UHXVkMFx2TWBcYDjLKHNUSlwwVA1gNQAzcEi4V2tSgqL2GDjdZE92dBCgwNB+GDBLfmGAbSpsKWwyAF0AOnZKKziYTVMLa0dJkABfScmC7SHdy324u3FvOWuNTTVzGE3zNQBzIx6LxA5D3R6ORzAIJBcD8azvLQ6GA8cEDZ4OTh4WgMVQfL4-P6A4GjIwotFxSHQ2EtCyaGBAA)

Comment: If it's a build time check, why not just declare `const something: Mini = ...`?

Comment: @GiulioCaccin - no need to mockingly include a link to Wikipedia article on what a subset is. I am a formal logic grad and know about set theory. The relation between `Omni` and `Mini` is very clear - what is not, at least to me, is what you are trying to get in the end. Is it type narrowing of `something`? Is it about avoiding `["c", "b"]`? If the latter, type layer is completely erased, so why would you expect that you can write the signature and avoid implementing it?

Comment: @GiulioCaccin - no hard feelings, just looked like you think we need to be told what a subset is. Usually, I am able to parse the question fairly easily, but I struggle with your end goal here, sorry. How are you going to use the `isMini` func? Seems like a standard case of user-defined type guards to me (you are using it to narrow the type of `something`, right?). If that's true, then I think you should not strive to keep the signature - a user-defined guard will resolve to `boolean`, but also has an added benefit of narrowing the type passed in as a parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229218/discussion-between-oleg-valter-and-giulio-caccin).

Comment: @captain-yossarian I have the need of creating a union type using `Extract`, I don't want to duplicate the value I put into the `Extract` anywhere else, and I want to _narrow_ the type from `Omni` to `Mini` with that method signature. Is there any way to do it?